# Handling telnet timeout/connection refused in pexpect python router

Tags: python-2.7, pexpect

I am trying to write a script where I need to ssh multiple jump server to access a router.

e.g LocalMachine----ssh---server1---ssh---server2---telnet/ssh---router

Not sure what is the best way of doing it, i tried achieving it through pexpect.
My requirement is when i telnet from server server2 to router and it timeout/connection refused i want try ssh
any suggestions please?

```
import time, pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh username@server-1')   ##########ssh to 1st Jump server
child.expect('password: ')
child.sendline('abc')
child.expect('$')
child.sendline('ssh username@server-2')   ##########ssh to 2nd Jump server
print child.before
child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('xyz')
child.expect('$')
print child.before
host=raw_input("Enter Router name: ")    

try:
    print "Trying Telnet ", host
    child.sendline(' telnet ' + host)  ### router telnet at this point i want if telnet is timeout/connection refused try ssh
    print child.before
except pexpect.TIMEOUT: 
    print child.before
else:
    child.expect(':')
    child.sendline("User")
    child.expect(":")
    child.sendline('passwprd')
    child.expect('#')
    child.sendline("\n")
    child.expect("#")
finally:
    print "Trying SSH ", host
    child.sendline(' ssh -l User ' + host)
    print child.before
    child.expect(":")
    child.sendline('password')
    child.expect('#')
    child.sendline("\n")

print child.before
child.interact()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pexpect.TIMEOUT` exception would be raised by the program instance running on your machine. It does not know if there is a timeout for the `telnet` instance running on the remote machine that you have ssh'ed to. The only way you can see if the telnet connection has a timeout or similar error, ie. connection refused, is to look at the output from the the process through `pexpect`. If you look at the [documentation](http://www.bx.psu.edu/~nate/pexpect/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.expect) for `expect` it says that you can give a list of conditions - this could be one way to go.

For example:

```
index = p.expect (['timeout', 'connection refused])  # Fill in correct words :)
```

Comment: tried using below but the value if i is always "$" ..what is the mistake?

i = child.expect(["Username:","$", "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?","password:",">"])